# Does rails 5 have a sandbox mode for console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried running the console by `rails c ––sandbox`

But the terminal throws this error

```
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

/home/workstation/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:236:in `resolve_symbol_connection': '––sandbox' database is not configured. Available: ["default", "development", "test", "production"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

In older rails versions it worked out of the box. So it looks like now rails wont have sandbox mode or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a dash(–) instead of a hyphen(-). This works in Rails 5.

```
rails c --sandbox
```

Comment: Yup, this makes `rails c` think you want to start in an environment called `––sandbox`, which is obviously not configured.

Comment: indeed...I tried with the dash several times with no luck then I found a codeschool blog which mentions dash (unfortunately) aswell. After copy pasting that I thought it was changed or so...Thanks a lot..